# Why do NumPy vsplits / hsplits not follow the usual programming convention of starting an index from 0?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say you have an array:

```
arr1 = np.arange(16)
```

You can get the second element by slicing as:

```
arr1[ 1 : 2]
```

Notice how we always start counting any indices from 0.

But NumPy seems to break that rule while splitting. When you split it will start the indices from 0 (for row and column) which feels counterintuitive.

```
grid = arr1.reshape(4,4)
print(grid)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0, 1, 2, 3],
[ 4, 5, 6, 7],
[ 8, 9, 10, 11],
[12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

Splitting this with numpy's vsplit:

```
np.vsplit(grid, [2])
```

Output:

```
[[0 1 2 3]
[4 5 6 7]]
[[ 8 9 10 11]
[12 13 14 15]]
```

This split happened after the line# 2. AKA, the vsplit / hsplit did not index the first line as 0.

Why does it not index from 0 which is intuitive?

Comment: It's giving you `arr[:2]` and `arr[2:]`.  A soft upper bound goes with 0 indexing, [0,2).  [1:2] is [1,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does index from 0. You're seeing it as indexing from 1 because you're interpreting the argument as "split after" instead of "split at"; the indices given in the second argument are where each subarray after the first *starts*, not where each subarray but the last *ends*.